# Problem in usb debugging

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, usb-debugging, app2sd, developer-options

I wanted to move all inbuilt apps on my Samsung Galaxy On7 to the sd card to free up space. To do this, I followed this [site](http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card/).

However, even after enabling USB debugging, the desktop is not being able to show the device in adb devices list. I had previously uninstalked all android emulators (like BlueStacks) and have the full android sdk tools and Android versions 5.0 to 7.0 installed on my computer.

Anyone can suggest why this happens?

Any other way to move inbuilt apps to sd card **without rooting** the device?

Comment: On the site you linked the author wrote: "After all of the comments I’ve seen up to this point, I think it’s safe to say that this tweak will not work on Lollipop (and probably Marshmallow) unless the device is rooted."

Comment: @kirodge what are the potential problems I might face if I root my device? Can the process be reversed?

Comment: @WRICHIKBASU see our [rooting tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and the details linked from there. Apart from that: if your device doesn't even show up on `adb devices`, and you're on Windows, it's probably a driver missing.

Comment: @lzzy My Driver was properly installed, and phone USB setting set to MTP.